# Jquery/JS not able to find chrome extension popup.html element after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I think, I have visited every possible question related to chrome extension in StackOverflow, but not found the solution to this weird problem.

I am trying to change the dom elements using jQuery.
Its changing and able to find the elements before the ajax request; **but not able to find after the ajax request.**

`console.log( $('#add_class_btn').get())`
This shows element before the ajax but not after that.

popup.html

```
        <div class="text-center d-none" id="add_class_btn">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success"> + Add this Data</button>
          <p>
            <small class="text-center">It seems this data is not in your list.</small>
          </p>
        </div>
       <div class="dashboardPage d-none">
          {....}
       </div>
        <div class="loginPage d-none">
          {....}
       </div>
       <div class="configPage d-none">
          {....}
       </div>
```

popup.js

```
console.log( $('#add_class_btn').get()) // element found returns <button>

const checkSomething = () => {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['token', 'transId'], function(res) {
    if (!res.token || res.token === 'undefined') {
      const a = confirm("You are not logged in yet to Our Chrome Extension!!")
      if (!a) return;
    }

    const token = res.token || null 
    const transId = res.transId || null
    let getdata= !!getdata? getdata() : false

    if(!getdata){
      return false
      // showConfigAdd()
    }

    const url_x = `http://localhost:3001/api/check/${getdata.id}`
    $.ajax({
      url: url_x,
      type: 'GET',
      headers: {
        authorization: token
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        if(!data.status){
          console.log( $('#add_class_btn').get()) // not found returns []
          $(`.loginPage`).addClass('d-none') //nothing happens
          $('.dashboardPage').addClass('d-none') //nothing happens
          $('.configPage').removeClass('d-none') //nothing happens
          $('#add_class_btn').removeClass('d-none')  //nothing happens
          console.log('status false,', data,) // return the data with message
        }else{
          console.log('data seems true')
              $('.dashboardPage').removeClass('d-none') //nothing happens
            if (transId || transId !== 'undefined') {
              loadDetails(token, transId)
            }
        }
      },
      error(e){
        console.log('OOps there is something wrong', e)
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I have also tried to use **JS** instead of $, but it is not able to find element too..

Comment: The posted fragment isn't sufficient to identify the problem. Maybe there's a problem elsewhere. The only obvious thing is that logging to console isn't really debugging. Instead, set a breakpoint on that line in devtools `Sources` panel, and when it hits look at the actual DOM in the `Elements` panel.

Comment: There is everything working fine, I got no error on the console. I checked dom and also used breakpoint, no changes noticed in debugging too. I am unable to understand why the jquery/js are not able to find the element. What may be the reason?

Comment: So far nothing makes sense to me so I can't help without trying the extension myself. Do you actually see the element in the [inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/images/panels/elements.png) when the breakpoint hits like this ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to find all the elements that I am targeting. 
I understand that it'll be hard for you to understand without testing. Can we share the code in js fiddle or something?

Comment: I'm not that interested in debugging it myself - my point was that this is something that can be investigated in debugger if you're using it fully and correctly. The problem you've described simply cannot happen so it means either a bug in Chrome or you're doing something weird like maybe not using the correct devtools (the popup has its own separate devtools).

Comment: I got the answer thanks @wOxxOm!

the reason was here,
(!getdata){
      return false
    }
it stops here.